# How to set the first slice angle

Tags: c#, excel, charts, pie-chart, epplus

As the title, I need to change the angle of the first slice of a pie chart. It looks like the setting in the following picture.

[image: Excel Setting]

For making the pie chart, I used Epplus as the follow:

```
ExcelPieChart pieChart = 
    worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("pieChart", eChartType.Pie) as ExcelPieChart;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637156/how-do-i-modify-a-chart-series-using-epplus. Use the `pieChart.Series.Add` method. The % is automatically calculated so you just make one of the values 1/4 of the total.

Comment: Thank for your reply. But I think it's not my problem. My problem is changing the setting of the angle of the first slice (this setting is available in excel). It's not right if I add a new series to "cover" it.